# How to set magento order shipping method?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

I am trying to set the shipping merthod in programatically created orders to a custom shipping method, here is a sample of my code...

```
setTelephone($shipping[Phone]);
// ->setFax($shipping->getFax());

$order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)->setShipping_method('flatrate_flatrate');
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You should set shipping method this way:

```
// Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
    ->collectShippingRates()
    ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
    ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
```

Check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87740/magento-programatically-create-order-with-php-code) for whole order creation