# What is setSendCconfirmation user for in create order function

Tags: magento-1.9

Sorry for my silly question:

I have followed this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87740/magento-programatically-create-order-with-php-code?answertab=active#tab-top) to create new orders by code and it worked but i don't know what is `setSendCconfirmation` function usage for. I tried to search `setSendCconfirmation` in Magento core but no result.

Answer (score 0):

> $quote->setSendCconfirmation(1) => meaning is send notification email to customer.
>
> $quote->setSendCconfirmation(0) => meaning is don't send notification email to
>   customer.

Comment: Can you let me know where does it defined in sources code? please