# How can I set created_at date for dynamically created order?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shell

I'am developing order generating [shell script](https://github.com/iekmuby/magento-order-generator) for my developing needs, which allow to generate orders for any period. I've used [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87742/14561) comment as template. Unfortunatelly, all orders has today created_at date. I can change this date after order was generated, but this is slow, because I need to load it first and save after. Is it possible to set created_at date before order generation?

Answer (score 0):

On line 192 in your shell script,

```
$order->setCreatedAt(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time()));
```

It will assign the create time as **current time**. If you need a specific time as a create time:

```
$order->setCreatedAt(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', strtotime('<your_date>')));
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: Nope, still today date

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Sorry, but it's the same as I did. Currently it's working as is, but I want to get rid of load/save order in loop and move it to the `createOrder` function to speed up this script a little.

Comment: I don't think you can prevent it in your case.